# How to ensure uniqueness in create_or_update without db level unique constraint in Django

Tags: mysql, django, concurrency, thread-safety, scalability

I am using django 1.10 with MySQL 5.7.

I have a table that has a unique_together constraint on multiple columns. But few of these columns are nullable. So the DB level uniqueness is not ensured for null entries in any of these fields.

I am using create_or_update method to ensure the uniqueness of rows at the application level. But in race conditions, even this does not ensure uniqueness as the system is horizontally scaled and multiple processes are concurrently trying to call the create_or_update function.

I think that this should be very a normal use-case for most of the high-scale services. How do we take care of this problem?

From what I think, My options can be:

1. save a string instead of keeping the entries nullable. (but it is a foreign-key field).
2. save a formatted string based on fields of unique together column and check uniqueness on that.

I feel that both these options would be unintuitive. What's be the commonly followed best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

Your options are not viable:

1. If you have a foreign key column as you said, you won't be able to set the column value as a string. Anyway, generate a string is not a good approach
2. Generating a string with the combination of you columns probably in some cases you will generate string not unique when you have the same values in the same columns and null in the other. May be you could think add a random key or something to your string generation but this will generate unique strings but will be wrong because unique rows will be "different"

In some cases the text fields in django are no NULL, are empty string unless you specify `null=True`, anyway, you should doing this :)

In my opinion you should analyze the business rules of your model, probably you are picking wrong fields are unique.

If you do a function check in the app level you need to specify that it is a transaction because it can raise errors

Answer (score 0):

If there is no error in the business rules nor the db planning, an alternative is to custom validate it in the models.

For example, inside the model:

```
def clean(self):
    """
    Select model objects but exclude the ones that has null on some fields
    """
    conflicting_instance = Models.objects.filter(
        relation_field=self.relation_field).exclude(field=None)
    if self.id:
        """
        This instance has already been saved, so it need to be filtered
        """
        conflicting_instance = conflicting_instance.exclude(pk=self.id)

    conflicting_list = [conflicting_instance.exists(),]

    if True in conflicting_list:
        """
        Return an error message if any of the validations is True
        """
        if conflicting_list[0]:
            raise ValidationError("""custom error.""")
    else:
        self.is_cleaned = True

def save(self):
    """
    If everything if clean, save it
    """
    if self.is_cleaned is True:
        super(Model, self).save()
    else:
        pass
```